# forming new columns in the form of one hot vector

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I have a dataframe :

```
customer | Department
----------------------
A        |   Food
B        |   Home
A        |   Office
C        |   Home
A        |   Home
B        |   Office
```

Both Customer and Department columns are String type

How can I convert different types of departments into new columns like a one hot vector so as to create the new data frame shown below :

```
 customer | Food | Home | Office
-----------------------------------
    A        1     1      1
    B        0     1      1
    C        0     1      0
```

Here the `Food`, `Home`, `Office` columns are of integer type and `customer` is of `String` type.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to `group` the data by `category` and `pivot` with aggregate as

```
val df = Seq(
  ("A", "Food"),
  ("B", "Home"),  
  ("A", "Office"),
  ("C", "Home"),
  ("A", "Home"),
  ("B", "Office")
).toDF("customer", "department")


df.groupBy("customer").pivot("department").agg(count("department"))
    .na.fill(0)
```

Output:

```
+--------+----+----+------+
|customer|Food|Home|Office|
+--------+----+----+------+
|B       |0   |1   |1     |
|C       |0   |1   |0     |
|A       |1   |1   |1     |
+--------+----+----+------+
```

Comment: Did this answer your problem? If so accept as an answer otherwise I am sure you won't be getting any help for the further questions.